# Trac html Notifications

Tags: trac

I am setting up Trac, on windows. I used a Bitnami installer. It is the newest stable version 1.2.3. I have a lot of stuff setup, including notifications, but I want to see HTML notifications. The plain text emails look wierd.
I did add the TracHtmlNotificationPlugin. Before doing that I was not getting emails with the default_format.email set to text/html.
Now I get the emails but they are still in plain text.

This is my trac.ini notification section. Let me know if I am missing something.

```
[notification]  
admit_domains = domain.com  
ambiguous_char_width = single  
batch_subject_template = ${prefix} Batch modify: ${tickets_descr}  
default_format.email = text/html  
email_sender = HtmlNotificationSmtpEmailSender  
ignore_domains =   
message_id_hash = md5  
mime_encoding = base64  
sendmail_path =   
smtp_always_bcc =   
smtp_always_cc =   
smtp_default_domain =   
smtp_enabled = enabled  
smtp_from = trac@domain.com  
smtp_from_author = disabled  
smtp_from_name =   
smtp_password =   
smtp_port = 25  
smtp_replyto =   
smtp_server = smtp.domain.com  
smtp_subject_prefix =   
smtp_user =   
ticket_subject_template = ${prefix} #${ticket.id}: ${summary}  
use_public_cc = disabled  
use_short_addr = disabled  
use_tls = disabled
```

I have my domain replaced in the real file.
Like I said I get emails now, just not html emails.

Edit:
I changed back the setting and now

```
Trac[web_ui] ERROR: Failure sending notification on change to ticket #7: KeyError: 'class'
```

Edit 2:
Fixed the error by putting the htmlnotification_ticket.html file (from the plugin) into the templates directory.

Comment: For 1.2.3 you shouldn't change `email_sender` from the default value. Use `SmtpEmailSender`. Make sure you haven't overridden the format in the [notification-subscriber](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracNotification#ExampleConfigurationdefaultsubscriptions) section or the user's *Notification Preferences* (see `/prefs/notification`). If that doesn't fix the issue, [enable debug logging](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTroubleshooting#ChecktheLogs).

Comment: I changed the email_sender setting back to SmtpEmailSender. Then I saw in the debug log that it couldn't find the template HtmlNotification_ticket.html. So I made one and put it in the templates folder. Now I get the error
    Trac[web_ui] ERROR: Failure sending notification on change to ticket #7: 
        KeyError: 'class'

Comment: This looks like an installation issue. You shouldn't have to copy the template into the `templates` directory. What steps did you follow to install the plugin?

Comment: I tested with Trac 1.2.3 by building the egg `python setup.py bdist_egg` and copying `dist/TracHtmlNotificationPlugin-0.12.0.1-py2.7.egg` to the environment `plugins` directory. Seems to work fine. There are [other ways to install](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracPlugins#InstallingaTracplugin) as well.

Comment: Yes, I messed up by just installing the plugin by uploading the notification.py file, in the web interface.

Comment: Ah, okay, makes sense. So all issues resolved now?